# What is this thorny tree with small, oval leaves, and seed pods?

Tags: identification, trees

I found this tree growing on a farm on the outskirts of Johannesburg, South Africa. It has really nasty thorns sticking out all over.

<sub>*Click on pictures for larger view.*</sub>

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like a Honey Locust. Not sure what it's doing in South Africa though, as it is native to North America. Someone must have planted it there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_locust.

Edit: From [tcpermaculture.com](http://tcpermaculture.com/site/2013/08/01/permaculture-plants-honey-locust/)

> **History:**
>   Native and widespread in central North America. It was used by Native Americans as a supplementary food source. It has been used in more recent times as a fast-growing, ornamental, shade tree, and thornless varieties have been developed. It has been naturalized in most of eastern North America and it ***has been introduced*** to India, ***South Africa***, New Zealand, and Australia. Some consider it a weed tree in these locations.

[image]

Comment: Those thorns look lethal - ouch

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a match. It does look similar. The seed pods on the trees that I saw do not twist or spiral, they're quite straight.

Comment: Honey locust is on our weeds list, so I'd be really sad if that's what this is.

Comment: @RichieACC seriously I wouldn't put much stock in the weed list. In Florida the Pin Oak (Quercus virginiania) is listed a a weed. A majestic tree like an oak is a weed? Don't worry too much about it. Locusts and other acacias of all types make great honey bee food and produce delicious honey.

Comment: https://lowertrentconservation.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/treevia-honey-locust-unhuggable-yet-irresistable/

That site has a photo showing the seed pods that convince me that your answer is correct. I am accepting it as such. Thank you!

Comment: @Rosie, I've had a look on Google now. The trees that I saw had the thorns on their trunks trimmed off, because they're in a playground. Their natural thorns are insane. I would not like to tangle with one of these. But it's a really pretty tree, so I think it's worth it.

Comment: Just as long a they are above head height and out of reach, I think you're right. Several seasons of interest too.

Answer (score 1):

Tamarind? It is from Africa. Unlike Honey Locust  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamarind

Comment: That is not the tree. It's similar. The fruits and seed pods do not match.